# Multiple instances of autocomplete jquery on master page

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have two jquery for getting data from database on master page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            SearchText1();
        });
        function SearchText1() {
            $("#txtSearch2").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "ItemGetter.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                        data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch2').value + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data.d);
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

and the other one!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText1();
    });
    function SearchText1() {
        $(".manish").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "ItemGetter.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch1').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and the two textboxes on which I am trying to implement Autocomplete are:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtSearch2" placeholder="Search Item" class="bjg autosuggest" runat="server" style="margin-top:8px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox id="txtSearch1" placeholder="Search Item" class="manish" runat="server" style="margin-top:8px"></asp:TextBox>
```

I have noticed that whichever script I write first doesn't work. I have also tried different classes as selectors, I have also tried using id's of textboxes. But this is something which I cannot understand. Even I tried to put one textbox in master page and the other in the content page. but nothing seems to work for me. please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

> Your function contains duplicates please make it one function. i added
>   one class name "textClass" and use it jquery.

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtSearch2" placeholder="Search Item" class="bjg autosuggest textClass" runat="server" style="margin-top:8px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox id="txtSearch1" placeholder="Search Item" class="manish textClass" runat="server" style="margin-top:8px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            SearchText1();

            function SearchText1() {
            $(".textClass").autocomplete({
                var that = $(this);
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "ItemGetter.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                        data: "{'username':'" + that.val() + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data.d);
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        });
```

or

```
$(["id^='txtSearch']").autocomplete ({ // here your code });
```